# no module named scipy.linalg.dsolve.umfpack

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, libraries, umfpack

I was trying to install Dioptas using `python setup_win_32.py install`.

During the installation I got the following error:

> no module named scipy.linalg.dsolve.umfpack

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

I am running on Windows 7 (32-bit) and have installed all the following required libraries:

- python 2.7
- PyQt4
- numpy
- scipy
- pyFAI
- fabio
- pyqtgraph
- scikit-image
- pyopencl
- fftw3

Answer (score 1):

UMFPACK wrapper has been [removed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3178) from scipy starting from version 0.14.
A replacement is available as a [scikit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-umfpack/0.1).